# Most efficient way to remove all linebreaks in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, replace, line-breaks

I have a macro which iterates over column C, anytime the cell is not empty it opens a file referenced in Column B, searches this newly opened file for a string that is written in column A and then replaces the content of that cell with what is written in column C. My problem though is that in the newly opened file, there are line breaks in some columns (sometimes trailing, sometimes where there should only be a space), so the macro doesn't find the right cell.

I was thinking to solve this I write another macro which goes through those files and replaces every line break with a space. It's basically just

```
For Each Cell In Worksheet.Range(Cells.Address)
    Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, Chr(10), " ")
Next
```

This seems to work, but I can't run it without excel crashing. Are there more efficient ways to do this? Or maybe all together a better approach to my problem? Thanks.

Comment: There can be multiple line breaks in a worksheet and I don't know where/how many, how else would I make sure to replace every line break with a space? I'm sorry if this is obvious, I'm a beginner with VBA and that seemed to be the logical way to me.

Comment: `Worksheet.UsedRange.Replace(Chr(10), " ")`.... though obviously use a different variable name than `Worksheet`.

Answer (score 0):

The VBA DoEvents function temporarily pauses a running macro, giving Excel a chance to process key presses, mouse clicks, and other operating system messages.

In long-running macros, Excel can appear to hang and become unresponsive, and the macro may be impossible to interrupt.  If DoEvents is included in your code, users can be assured that the macro is still running, and can still interrupt execution if necessary.

```
For Each Cell In Worksheet.Range(Cells.Address)
    Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, Chr(10), " ")
    DoEvents
Next
```

**Source**: [automateexcel](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/doevents/)

Answer (score 0):

This *(I hope)* is an implementation of BigBen's suggestion for the active sheet:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    r.Replace Chr(10), " "
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

The code above relies on the proper worksheet being `Active`.  A safer alternative would be to use something more explicit like:

```
Set r = Sheets("my data").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

NOTE:

We are using the `.Replace()` Method rather than the `Replace()` function.

Comment: Thanks for that! I just tried it, and while it finishes very quickly and must be editing something (when I want to close the newly opened file it asks me if I want so save the changes) it does not detect the line breaks (or at least not the ones I am checking for as a test) like my "broken solution". From the above I am sure that Chr(10) is the right linebreak to look for (I think there are 3 different ones?), so that is not the problem, but I'm unsure what else could be

Comment: @Brian  See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: I'm not sure I'm referencing the sheet correctly. I do 

`Set destWB = Workbooks.Open(fileName)` and

`Set destSH = destWB.Sheets("Sheet name")`.

With your first code I tried `destSH.Activate` and `destSH.Select`, now I'm just substituting `Sheets("my data")` with `destSH` , should I reference that sheet differently?